# How to remove headers from a retrieved range or a getValues array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get in an array the range name of the GSheet inside appscript, however, it puts inside the array all the complete namerange, for example, to get only the data and not the headers.

I tried with `.offset()`, do you know any other way?

This is what I did:

```
var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName('id').offset(1,0).getValues();
```

However, when I do this even if I don't get the header, I still get an array with the size as if I had the header.

Answer (score 3):

I think that in your showing script, `offset(1,0)` means that the 1st row is moved to one row. In this case, the number of data rows is not changed. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. In your situation, I think that the method of `offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows)` can be used as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName('id');
var id = range.offset(1, 0, range.getNumRows() - 1).getValues();
```

#### Note:

- As another direction, in order to remove the header row, I thought that you can also use `shift()` and as follows.

  ```js
  var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName('id').getValues();
  id.shift();
  ```

  ```js
  var [, ...id] = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName('id').getValues();
  ```

#### References:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)
- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows)
- [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)